# PrintWriter new line issue. Working fine in Eclipse

Tags: java

Basically I have the following method that is a bit overkill I know, but I'm learning.....

```
public String showOrder() {
        String x = "";
        x = "Order Summary: \n ";
        for (Order order : orders) {
            x += "    Product Id: " + order.getProductCode() + "    Product Description: " + order.getProductDesc() + 
                    "    Order Quantity: " + order.getQuantity() + "    Order Cost: £" + order.getCost() + "\n "; 
        }
        x += "Total Cost: "+ getTotalCost() + "p        Number of Orders: " + numOfOrders() + "     Total Products: " + numOfProducts();
        return x;
    }
```

This is returning in my test program as I'd expect with each order on its own line.

```
 Product Id: 1...etcetc
 Product Id  2...etcetc
 Product Id  3...etcetc
```

But, when I create a PrintWriter the showOrder() method prints out one long list in my .txt. file.

```
PrintWriter cartReceipt = new PrintWriter("Cart.txt");

        cartReceipt.println(cart1.showOrder());
        cartReceipt.flush();
        cartReceipt.close();
```

Is there a way to make the same method return a nice orderly list in the txt file like it does in the IDE?

Comment: As your question was already solved, I still have a side note. You are creating a ton of strings for a large list (order). In Java strings are immutable. Every time you do "x += sth" you create a new string. Instead you should use a StringBuilder to append your information and then create a string out of it and return it in the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is `\n` is not a portable line ending. You can use [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) like

```
x += "    Product Id: " + order.getProductCode()
        + "    Product Description: " + order.getProductDesc()
        + "    Order Quantity: " + order.getQuantity() 
        + "    Order Cost: £" + order.getCost() + System.lineSeparator();
```

However, it would be more efficient if you *streamed* the write operation to the `PrintWriter` (since you don't seem to use the `String` *except* for writing the orders). You could pass the `PrintWriter` into the writing method. Something like,

```
public void writeOrder(PrintWriter pw) {
    pw.println("Order Summary:");
    for (Order order : orders) {
        // NOTE: If possible, I would move this code into Order.toString()
        //       and then use pw.println(order);
        pw.print("    Product Id: ");
        pw.print(order.getProductCode());
        pw.print("    Product Description: ");
        pw.print(order.getProductDesc());
        pw.print("    Order Quantity: ");
        pw.print(order.getQuantity());
        pw.print("    Order Cost: £");
        pw.println(order.getCost());
    }
    pw.print("Total Cost: ");
    pw.print(getTotalCost());
    pw.print("p        Number of Orders: ");
    pw.print(numOfOrders());
    pw.print("     Total Products: ");
    pw.println(numOfProducts());
}
```

Comment: Interesting, Java's docs are inconsistent. `\n` is a newline according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Comment: "[Newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)" is a character or char sequence depending on the OS. For Unix/Linux it's LF, for Windows it's CR+LF. The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) states that `\n` is a newline (it makes no mention of linefeed), which implies that it will expand to the correct character(s) for the OS it's on. Obviously the docs are wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately it's become common for "\n" to be called a newline. It's not; it's a linefeed. A linefeed on its own is the newline on Linux, whereas a newline on Windows is a linefeed plus carriage return. It's just sloppy use of language.

Answer (score 3):

You are using "\n" as a newline character. If you are using Notepad to read the .txt file, it doesn't recognize the '\n' character as a newline (it is normally "\r\n" on Windows) and therefore displays all lines on the same line. If you use your IDE to read the .txt file, it will probably display it the way you expect.

The correct way to write your code is to use [`System.lineSeparator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator()). Another change you ought to make in your code is purely for performance reasons: if you are building a string one piece at a time in a loop, you should use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of String:

```
public String showOrder() {
    StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder("Order Summary:");
    x.append(System.lineSeparator());
    for (Order order : orders) {
        x.append("    Product Id: ").append(order.getProductCode()
            .append("    Product Description: ").append(order.getProductDesc())
            .append("    Order Quantity: ").append(order.getQuantity())
            .append("    Order Cost: £").append(order.getCost())
            .append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    x.append("Total Cost: ").append(getTotalCost())
        .append("p        Number of Orders: ").append(numOfOrders())
        .append("     Total Products: ").append(numOfProducts())
        .append(System.lineSeparator());
    return x.toString();
}
```

Lastly, be careful when you use non-ASCII characters like "£" in your source file. Make sure you are using the same character encoding (e.g. UTF-8 or Windows-1252) as `javac` expects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you still have to be careful even when the '£' is in a string? I'm only two months into Java so I'm very naive! Cheers.

Comment: @Matt yes, you do, because the compiler will read the source (including the string contents) and translate it into "Unicode" (UTF-16 actually) assuming your source is in the specified (or default) encoding. The literal string will be translated using your encoding to have 16-bit characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `"\n"` with `"\r\n"` and see if it helps. I suspect if this is the interpretation of the line separator by the app. For example, there is `'\n'` (the LF character) in the code, but the app you use to read the file does not interpret it into a new line.